# Subform not loading

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a form when it loads, one of the subforms displays as a white blank box. However if I then go to design view then back to Form view the subform loads perfectly. Can anyone help.

Thank You. DR ,

http://transparent-aluminium.net/resources/AccessHelp.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The detail section of a form goes completely blank if both these conditions
are met:
(a) There are no records to display, and
(b) No new records can be added.

Condition (a) might be because of the way the recordset if filtered.
Condition (b) might be because the form's AllowAdditions property is set to
No, or because the form is based on a read-only query.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I have come up with a inefficient solution to the sub form not loading when the form first loads.

Answer (score 0):

After being unable to solve it (and unable to focus on the screen) at 0230 last night I have come up with a solution. As the from loads I blank the SourceObject and then reassign it to the form and requery the form.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.STMonth = Me.Month_Picker

Me.SSTATMENTqryCustomerStmtALL_CrosstabXX_subform.SourceObject = ""
Me.SSTATMENTqryCustomerStmtALL_CrosstabXX_subform.SourceObject = "SSTATMENTqryCustomerStmtALL_CrosstabXX_subform"

DoCmd.Requery

Call Command6_Click
End Sub
```

Its not particulate efficient but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this post because I was having the same problem.  After MANY hours, I figured out what my problem was.

I was opening the form from a button on the switchboard using the wrong format.
I used

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTaskPackages", acNormal, , , acFormAdd, acDialog
```

instead of

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmTaskPackages", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acDialog
```

Which is why it works after you put the form in design mode for a second; it is no longer opening the form using that code.
I hope this helps and this is my first post with code so sorry if my formatting is bad.